# Custom tone for new text messages etc

Tags: settings, audio, notifications

Mango introduced the ability to create and add custom ringtones to your phone, but is there a way (programmatic or otherwise) to create a custom tone to be used for a new text message or meeting reminder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is finally possible (see UserVoice update [here](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2281201-custom-sounds-for-sms-mms-email-notifications-e)). Just add your audio file (<30k) to the Ringtones folder on your device.

It should now show up under the `Custom` section when selecting your new notification sound.

Answer (score 6):

As of now, you can't **officially** change the notification sounds. You will need to live with what shipped on your phone. What Mango introduced is the ability to have custom ring-tones. You would think they are synonymous, but no dice there.

Now that the official answer is out of the way, it you have a developer-unlocked device, and have it rooted, I believe you can replace the sounds on the phone with new ones. Be warned that this does not add new. It **replaces** existing. Unless you backed them up, they will be gone forever.

[This thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=938106) on the XDA forums is a bit of a start to help you do it. [And here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=11292452) is a thread with custom sounds